# Changing the name of a group (ABGroup) in iOS address book

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

I would like to add the ability to change the name of a group in the address book. However I can't seem to find an existing method to do this.

Does anyone know if such a method exists? Or is my only option to copy the members of the group, add them to a new group with the new name, and delete the old group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function

```
bool ABRecordSetValue (ABRecordRef record,ABPropertyID property,CFTypeRef value,CFErrorRef *error);
```

`record` is the reference to the group record in the address book
`property` is the `kABGroupNameProperty` property that represents the group name
`value` is the new group name

Afterwards you have of course to save the address book with

```
OK = ABAddressBookSave(addressBookRef, &error);
```

Comment: No idea where my head was yesterday. I use that all the time for actual contacts, don't know why I didn't think to use it for a group. Thank you.